# Why isn't the Berlin - Munich fast train connection updated in travel maps?

Tags: trains, europe, germany

There should be a fast train between Berlin and Munich, but [Google Maps](https://www.google.fi/maps/dir/Berlin,+Germany/Munich,+Germany/@50.3470158,8.6608297,7z/data=!4m15!4m14!1m5!1m1!1s0x47a84e373f035901:0x42120465b5e3b70!2m2!1d13.404954!2d52.5200066!1m5!1m1!1s0x479e75f9a38c5fd9:0x10cb84a7db1987d!2m2!1d11.5819805!2d48.1351253!3e3!5i3?hl=en) does not reflect it in Schedule Explorer: best time us 4 hours.

Comment: Have you checked out on one of the European rail sites, like bahn.de? Google does not claim to be up to date, just to be helpful.

Comment: A question about one special service provider not updating their data is not a good one for StackExchange. And: For me  Google shows this connection.

Comment: @asdfex What is the total min time it shows?

Answer (score 10):

A connection of less than 4 hours is only achieved when using the special ICE Sprinter connections. Compared to the standard connection, these trains skip some of the stops. They leave both Munich and Berlin around 6:00, 12:00 and 18:00. The precise times can be found in the table on [this page](https://www.zugreiseblog.de/zug-muenchen-berlin/).

Secondly, the search as you entered it in Google Maps suggests taking a regional train from Berlin Central Station to Berlin Südkreuz and only enter the ICE there. This doesn't make much sense as the ICE stops at the central station as well and pushes the travel time over 4 hours.

I suggest using the search at [bahn.com](https://www.bahn.com/en/view/index.shtml) instead. It's available in a couple of languages including English.

Comment: There is no mandatory reservation in ICE sprinter trains.

Comment: What is the min time by Bahn.de? I get 4H: https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/en?ld=37243&protocol=https:&seqnr=2&ident=e5.011855243.1518377639&rt=1&OK#focus

Comment: The train at 6 in the morning indeed takes 4:02, while the other two later in the day take 3:58. The "less than 4 hours" used in their marketing really means just slightly less.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 - the time shown in Google is about correct, but it has the error taking an RB first as helm pointed out. And the route shown on the map is the wrong one, not the new high speed tracks.

Answer (score 2):

I see a roughly-four-hour ICE trip [here](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Berlin,+Germany/Munich,+Germany/@50.3087833,8.6818212,7z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m16!4m15!1m5!1m1!1s0x47a84e373f035901:0x42120465b5e3b70!2m2!1d13.404954!2d52.5200066!1m5!1m1!1s0x479e75f9a38c5fd9:0x10cb84a7db1987d!2m2!1d11.5819805!2d48.1351253!2m1!5e2!3e3?shorturl=1) (the specific trip is [here](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Berlin,+Germany/Munich,+Germany/@50.3087867,9.5265805,7z/am=t/data=!3m1!4b1!4m19!4m18!1m5!1m1!1s0x47a84e373f035901:0x42120465b5e3b70!2m2!1d13.404954!2d52.5200066!1m5!1m1!1s0x479e75f9a38c5fd9:0x10cb84a7db1987d!2m2!1d11.5819805!2d48.1351253!2m3!5e2!6e4!8j1518380881!3e3!5i1)).  Some caveats:

- I clicked the "Options" link and then checked the "trains" checkbox.  This eliminates the distracting (and slow) bus trips from the search results.
- It's possible that that link will show you a different set of trains, since for all I know, it's looking at trains that leave "now", and you will click that link at a different time than I did, so the set of trains will differ.
- You may have to scroll through all the longer, indirect trips in order to see the short direct ones.  I recommend that you click the "schedule explorer" link; that brings up a window in which it's (relatively) easy to scroll through the various options.